# Getting an infinite loop and can't see why - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm writing a simple little Connect 4 game and I'm running into an infinite loop on one of my functions:

```
var reds = 0;
var greens = 0;

function checkEmpty(div) {
    var empty = false;
    var clicked = $(div).attr('id');
    console.log(clicked);
    var idnum = parseInt(clicked.substr(6));
    while (idnum < 43) {
        idnum = idnum + 7;
    }
    console.log("idnum=" + idnum);
    while (empty == false) {
        for (var i = idnum; i > 0; i - 7) {
            idnumStr = idnum.toString();
            var checking = $('#square' + idnumStr);
            var str = checking.attr('class');
            empty = str.includes('empty');
            console.log(empty);
            var divToFill = checking;
        }
    }

    return divToFill;
}

function addDisc(div) {
    if (reds > greens) {
        $(div).addClass('green');
        greens++;
        console.log("greens=" + greens);
    } else {
        $(div).addClass('red');
        reds++;
        console.log("reds=" + reds);
    };
    $(div).removeClass('empty');
}

$(function() {
    var i = 1;
    //add a numbered id to every game square
    $('.game-square').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('id', 'square' + i);
        i++;
        //add an on click event handler to every game square

        //onclick functions
        $(this).on('click', function() {
            var divToFill = checkEmpty(this);
            addDisc(divToFill);
        })
    })
})
```

Here is a link to the codepen http://codepen.io/Gobias___/pen/xOwNOd

If you click on one of the circles and watch the browser's console, you'll see that it returns true over 3000 times. I can't figure out what I've done that makes it do that. I want the code to stop as soon as it returns empty = true. empty starts out false because I only want the code to run on divs that do not already have class .green or .red.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Make sure you debug the code where you have ``while`` and ``for`` loops.

May be your ``empty`` variable is never ``true`` or your ``i`` variable is never equal to ``0``

Comment: Have you added 'id' attribute to the game-square classes? In the codepen you shared, its not there.

Comment: OP check out vp_arth's answer. You are not decrementing your i.

Comment: `while (idnum < 43) { idnum = idnum + 7; }` What's the point of this? Just set `idnum = 49` if that's what you need.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, it's something like `idnum = 42 + (idnum%7 || 7)`

Comment: @Rory, I'm using that to ensure that the player can click on any div and it will end up filling in the correct one. So if I clicked on the first div at the top, it has an id of - square1. In order to get to the bottom I add 7 until it reaches at least 43. The bottom row divs are id 43-49. As soon as it's over 42, it's at the bottom row and I can start checking to see which spaces are empty from the bottom up. I don't know if that's a clear explanation tbh.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> for (var i = idnum; i > 0; i - 7);

You do not change the `i`.

Do you want to decrement it by 7?

Change your `for` loop to the one shown below:

```
for (var i = idnum; i > 0; i -= 7) {
  // ...
}
```

---

You also do not use loop variable in the loop body. Instead, you use `idnum`, I think this can be issue.

```
while (empty == false) {
    for (var i = idnum; i > 0; i -= 7) {
        idnumStr = i.toString(); // changed to i
        var checking = $('#square' + idnumStr);
        var str = checking.attr('class');
        empty = str.includes('empty');
        console.log(empty);
        var divToFill = checking;
        // and don't forget to stop, when found empty
        if (empty) break;
    }
}
```

I add break if empty found, because if we go to next iteration we will override empty variable with smallest `i` related value.

You can also wrap `empty` assignment with `if (!empty) {empty = ...;}` to prevent this override, but I assume you can just break, because:

> I want the code to stop as soon as it returns empty = true

---

Offtop hint:

```
while (idnum < 43) {
    idnum = idnum + 7;
}
```

can be easy replaced with: `idnum = 42 + (idnum%7 || 7)`

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you. I knew it would be a simple oversight on my part. No matter how many times I looked over the code that never stood out to me. Now it works perfectly for the first row. However if I try to place a disc on the second row, it really does run infinitely. Whereas before it was running true 3000+ times, now it runs false and never stops.#

Comment: You didn't use `i` in the loop. Check the answer.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much. This works  perfectly. I knew it would be little things. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

Change to this:

```
for (var i = idnum; i > 0; i = i - 7) {
```

You are not decrementing the i in your for loop

Comment: Thank you. I missed that small detail which was very important. However as I said to vp-arth above, I now have another problem with the loop. It runs perfectly for the first row, but if I try to place a disc in a column where the first row is already filled, it runs false infinitely.

Comment: Look at @vp_arths answer. They fixed it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Building on what the others have posted You would want to change the value of empty inside the for loop. because obviously the string still checks the last string in the loop which would always return false.

```
while(empty==false){

for (var i = idnum; i > 0; i -= 7) {
   // your other codes
  if (!empty) {
   empty = str.includes('empty');
   }
}
```